# LDAP connection is unstable with WSO2

Tags: active-directory, wso2, ldap, wso2-identity-server

We are implementing WSO2 identity solution with Active directory. After implementation, we have observed that connection is unstable example - In total 10 attempts - It works successfully twice but fails in rest of the 8 attempts. Logs:-
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-10-19 12:44:35,475] [e96a3f67-1caf-421b-b5c3-c20e9eeef75f] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - Error occurred while obtaining LDAP connection. Connection URL: ldaps://XXXXXXXX:636/ org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error obtaining connection. [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090447, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 775, v3839 ]

---

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log, you're getting an error **49** with data **775** which means the "Account lockout".

You can check out the following link for more information on analyzing the LDAP error log:
https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/164943/vip-ldap-error-code-49.html

```
525 user object not found
52e invalid password/credential
53f credential policy violation
530 time restriction in place
531 not permitted to logon at this workstation
532 password expired / DN username mismatch
533 account disabled
568 too many context identifiers
701 account expired
773 username/password valid, must reset password
775 account lockout
```

More information on these specific errors can be found here:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Account%20Lockout

I hope this helps you to deal with this error.

Comment: Thanks, Nadun. When WSO2 logs showed error code 775, I tried the same user ID login outside of WSO2 and it worked fine which shows there might not be a user ID issue.

Comment: Audit logs : TID: [-1234] [2022-11-03 18:29:46,395] [3a5c9ec3-f1e7-4d42-b45d-d8de1be54014]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=admin@carbon.super Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"Users":["XX.XX/073867"]} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2022-11-03 18:30:10,114] [06313033-29c0-4b9f-ad53-62a1a34968b6]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=admin@carbon.super Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={} Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while getting user list, Error occurred while obtaining LDAP connection, LDAP connection circuit breaker state set to: open","Error Code":"34003"}